# White Screen on Site but wp-admin OK

Tags: errors, headers, plugin-contact-form-7, fatal-error

I am hoping someone can help me - I have white screen on my whole site but wp-admin is full access and will update ok.

I have done the following:

Enabled debug in config - got errors around headers already sent contact form 7 so have disabled that.

Checked the code in my header file, as it was telling me headers already sent.

Added a memory define on config but it said I had already added it -
   referring to the one I just added - something tells me it's doing
   stuff twice?

Checked the last loop i added in a page - removed it, saved and
   reloaded - that didn't fix it (it was working originally anyway as it din't break the site).

Now I have no error messages but also no visible site. And no idea how to fix it. Can add whatever code needed here if anyone can point in the right direction?

**UPDATE:** *I changed from the theme I am building to twenty fifteen and that loaded ok - think I have a php error somewhere - how do I find out where?*

Comment: - have you tried ob_start(); after get_header() ?
this will buffer output before display...

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: seems like there is a problem in your functions.php file.
plz add that code on the begining of functions.php file..

Comment: That's not done anything. Added functions.php to question.

Comment: I've not added it as it messes up :/

Comment: um then there must be some plugin that creating that problem. Try deactivating each of your plugin one at a time.

Comment: Yeah, the very quick fix for your problem will be to add ob_start(); at the begining of your function.php file .
But as you said you have already done that so 
 
If you have access to change your php.ini configuration file you can find and change or add the following

output_buffering = On

Comment: maybe I added ob_start(); wrongly.

Comment: Remove spaces before the first <?php tag in functions.php. .

Comment: Try to add these lines to your **functions.php** file (main theme folder): `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: What were you doing when the error started?

Answer (score 1):

It is usually because there are spaces, new lines, or other stuff before an opening `<?php` tag or after a closing `?>` tag, typically in wp-config.php or any of your theme or plugin files.

Please check your theme and remove white space from top and bottom of your files.

Comment: Thanks, I did that - checked all over, then viewed source on one of the pages and I had a bit of code wrong in the header. Wasn't showing on debug at all though. Soon as I got rid of the error, the debug worked again.

Comment: Glad it worked. Accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: It was viewing the source that helped, so if you want to update your answer to include that then I can accept the answer.